# Does Microsoft implement "Windows Defender"-like security for WSL 2 instances?

Tags: windows, virtualization, wsl

I'm not certain whether WSL 2 instances, running in Hyper-V, are actually scanned by Windows Defender.

I have found some articles on Google describing Window Defender's performance impact on WSL, but they are not mentioning whether they are talking about WSL 1 or WSL 2.

Indeed, it's possible for Windows Defender to scan WSL 1 instances, since they aare user-space processes running in Windows, and their file systems are rooted at folders (e.g. `C:\path\to\wsl1\dist`)

However, does Microsoft implement any "Windows Defender"-like security for WSL 2 instances?

Indeed, Windows Defender running in Windows cannot scan WSL 2 instances, since they are both running in Hyper-V. So, does Microsoft run any "Windows Defender"-like process in WSL 2 instances? Does Hyper-V perform any kind of monitoring of WSL 2 instances?

Comment: Do you mean: Is er a Windows Degfender process runing inside the WSL container? or do you mean to ask "Can Windows Defender protect from Linux based threats?"

Comment: I mean “any”. Does Windows implement any security for WSL2? Does it scan the file systems (virtual disks), does it monitor processes, etc.? Windows didn’t detect I downloaded Mimikatz into WSL2.

Comment: Did you download the windows version or the Linux version of minikatz? And I would suspect windows defender does not scan the virtual disks as such. But I have no proof of that.

Comment: @LvB - I downloaded the Windows version.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to ask if Defender can recognize malware in WSL, such as in an executable on disk. Defender does that for Windows but as far as I know it does not recognize malware in Linux executables.